# Trying to find two tracelogs within a certain time span

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to find two different tracelogs within a certain time frame of each other. I tried the below Datediff hoping it would work but it returns the following error:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

It seems like it's not happy that it has reached multiple instances within the subquery but I don't know how to fix that. The code I am trying is:

```
  SELECT[LogTimeStamp]
          ,[MachineName]
          ,[LogMessage]
      FROM [Abel].[dbo].[TraceLog]
    where   LogTimeStamp >'2016-12-05 13:15:21.377' 
                and
            DATEDIFF(hour, 
                (SELECT [LogTimeStamp] FROM [Abel].[dbo].[TraceLog] where LogMessage like '%Pos:416 F34Lab Procedure Code #%99111%'), 
                (SELECT [LogTimeStamp] FROM [Abel].[dbo].[TraceLog] where LogMessage like '%DELETION METHOD CALLED%')) < 1

            order by LogTimeStamp asc
```

Comment: please tag the dbms you are using.

Comment: Microsoft SQL server 2014